# Pressing infinite number keys in python

Tags: python, keypress, pynput

so I wanted to create a code in python that automatically type numbers from 1 to 100
and it doesn't work. Hope someone can help

Here's my code

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
n = 1

time.sleep(2)
while 1 == 1:
    keyboard.press(n)
    keyboard.release(n)
    n = n + 1
```

(I have "pynput" and "time" installed)

I tried reading error and from what I know have I think it's the problem with this characters "", but if I'm gonna add them I will not be able to add bigger number

Comment: Please edit your post and add the full text of the error message, pasted as text (not a screenshot).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the type of the variable to string:

```
while 1 = 1:
 for ch in str(n):
  keyboard.press(str(ch))
  keyboard.release(str(ch))
 n = n + 1
```

But you need to put a *for* loop because when the number is over 9, you need to send separately all digits for each number.

Answer (score 0):

check your conditions in while loop

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
n = 1

time.sleep(2)
while n <= 100:
    if n <10:
        press_key = str(n)
        keyboard.press(str(press_key))
        keyboard.release(str(press_key))
    elif n>=10 and n<=99:
        press_key_first_digit = str(n//10)
        press_key_second_digit = str(n%10)
        keyboard.press(str(press_key_first_digit))
        keyboard.release(str(press_key_first_digit))
        keyboard.press(str(press_key_second_digit))
        keyboard.release(str(press_key_second_digit))
    else:
        keyboard.press("1")
        keyboard.release("1")
        keyboard.press("0")
        keyboard.release("0")
        keyboard.press("0")
        keyboard.release("0")
    n = n + 1
```